# Falling oil prices but no benefits passed on to the end user; government's strategy

Tags: taxation, government, oil

Even though the oil prices have fallen rapidly in the recent years, the cost of petroleum products hasn't gone down in India.

Apart from raising more revenue, what are the other benefits the government derives from such a strategy?